# Is this a good way to implement state pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented

I would like to know if the code below is a good implementation of the state design pattern. Everywhere I see the state pattern to hold the context and a change in state doesn't return anything. But in my example below, I return the new state (i.e. North/east so on...). Please review and help.

```
public abstract class Direction
{
    public abstract Direction Right();


    public abstract Direction Left();
}


public sealed class East : Direction
{

    public East()

    { }


    public override Direction Left()
    {
        return new North();
    }


    public override Direction Right()
    {
        return new South();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "EAST";
    }
}
```

Similarly for other directions.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It already looks over-engineered to me.  Have a look at this example: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state/java/1

Comment: Ugg, that's also horribly hard-coded.

Comment: Here's an implementation of the state pattern. https://github.com/rubberduck203/VendingMachineKata

Comment: @ CandiedOrange What's hard-coded here? Is there any other direction you would return apart from South if you are facing East and turn Right?

By this logic I feel whole state design pattern itself it hard-coded.

Comment: @  RubberDuck thanks. I saw your example. Only difference I see is you are keeping the current state(m_current_state) in the class where I am returning it. Keeping it in the class I feel is tight coupling.

Comment: @  Robert Harvey LOL, the example you sent I feel that if super engineered. When replying please explain your thoughts in writing, I don't understand which part is over engineered here, by that idea whole SOLID pattern what it just do is over engineering,

Comment: Well, you really don't need **any** of this.  All you really need is a class with **one state variable** that holds the current state (it can be an enum), and **a method that advances the state** to the next valid state from the one currently stored in the state variable.  You need one line of code for the state variable, and a `switch` statement with a `case` (two lines of code) for each state change.  If the states can be represented by a monotonically increasing `int`, you don't even need the `switch` .The rest of the code in this pattern is just gratuitous boilerplate.

Comment: If you need a method that prints the current state, you can put that in the ToString() method of the enum (where it belongs), or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value

Comment: @ Robert Harvey c# doesn't allow extending enums(not a fan of extesnion methods), so only way to for are classes, and as you said ToString has been overriden in above classes, Classes are more SOLID in this scneario then enums.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an enum; it can simply be a counter variable (an int), if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an example of the state pattern, but you're almost there.

The problem with the way you have it now can be demonstrated with this example:

```
void Turn(Direction d, int degrees)
{
    switch (degrees)
    {
        case 90: d = d.Right();
        case -90: d = d.Left();
    }
}

void Example()
{
    Direction d = new East();
    Turn(d, 90);
    Turn(d, 90);
    Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());  //Prints East.  Should print West!!!
}
```

The issue is that the class doesn't actually contain state that tells you what direction it faces.  It *is* the state.  So if you change direction, somehow you have to go back and change every reference to the object to something else.  if you don't do that, state is lost.

A correct state pattern implementation would include a container:

```
class DirectionState 
{
    private Direction _state;

    public DirectionState(Direction initialDirection) { _state = initialDirection; }

    public void Left()  { _state = _state.Left(); }
    public void Right() { _state = _state.Right();}
    public string ToString() { return _state.ToString(); }
}
```

Then this would work:

```
void Turn(DirectionState d, int degrees)
{
    switch (degrees)
    {
        case 90: d = d.Right();
        case -90: d = d.Left();
    }
}

void Example()
{
    DirectionState d = new DirectionState(new East());
    Turn(d, 90);
    Turn(d, 90);
    Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());  //Prints West
}
```

Comment: Thanks John for the reply.  In my implementation use case of Direction class would be like 

    Direction d = new East();
   d= Turn(d, 90); //direction should return the new state.
    d= Turn(d, 90);
    Console.WriteLine(d.ToString()); // Now it gives west instead of east.

So actor holds the responsibility of holding the current state.

Thanks

Comment: Sure, that would work.  Just sayin, that is not the State Pattern.

Comment: I think we both are talking the same thing here :) your DirectionState  class is represented by another class(called ROBOT) in my program, so ROBOT saves the state and maintains it.

Comment: Sorry I haven't included Robot class in the question.